# godot 4(using gdscript) error Invalid set index 'x' (on base 'callable') with value type of 'vector2' error when running my code

Tags: gdscript, godot4

My Code:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var PlayerVelocity = 100
var direction = Vector2(0, 0)

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        direction.x = velocity
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        direction = -velocity
    else:
        direction = 0

    direction = move_and_slide
```

And also btw i am watching this tutorial: [Link:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXG62XhDql4)

I tried to make a character controller for my 2d game.
And the outcome was this error: godot 4 error Invalid set index 'x' (on base 'callable') with value type of 'vector2'

Answer (score 0):

> direction.x = velocity

This is assigning the float `x` property of a `Vector2` a whole entire `Vector2`.

You probably meant: `direction.x = velocity.x`

> direction = -velocity

This has the correct types but you probably meant: `direction.x = -velocity.x`.

> direction = 0

This is assigning the integer 0 to `direction` which is supposed to be a `Vector2`.

> direction = move_and_slide

This assigns the method `move_and_slide` to `direction` as a `Callable`.  **Rather than** *calling* `move_and_slide()` and assigning the result to `direction`:

```
direction = move_and_slide()
```

***However*** in Godot 4, `move_and_slide()` returns a `bool`, where true means it has collided with something, and not a `Vector2`.

---

Furthermore, `direction` is redundant as we have `velocity` which is both direction and speed.

We can get a "direction" from the `velocity` with `velocity.normalized()`.

---

The linked tutorial is for Godot v3. You'll have to check the relevant class reference docs when you run into certain errors to see what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

This could be considered a typo, but still, I believe it is useful to answer, as it is not just a transcription error.

Here:

```
direction = move_and_slide
```

You are not calling the method `move_and_slide`, instead you are getting a refence to it. And Godot cannot get the `x` of a reference to a method, hence the error.

To call it you would do this:

```
direction = move_and_slide()
```

---

Regardless, the tutorial is for Godot 3. *You can see the version in the video, it is on Godot's Project Manager on the top right, or in the editor in the bottom.*

And it was either incorrect or confusing depending how you look at it, as `move_and_slide` didn't return a direction, it returned a velocity.

Plus, the `velocity` variable in the tutorial is not a velocity, it is a speed (it does not have direction, velocity is speed with a direction).

I would like to encourage you to find an updated tutorial.

---

Now, Godot has types. Here:

```
var direction = Vector2(0, 0)
```

The type of the variable `direction` is variant. It could hold anything. It just happens to be initialized with a `Vector2`. You can define the variable as a `Vector2` explictly:

```
var direction:Vector2 = Vector2(0, 0)
```

Or implicitly (inferred from the initialization):

```
var direction := Vector2(0, 0)
```

Then Godot would have pointed at the problematic line (as it would have been assigning something that is not a `Vector2` to a `Vector2` variable).

---

Furthermore, in Godot 4, `move_and_slide` returns a `bool` which indicates if there was a collision or not. And that is not what you want.

Also `velocity` is what you want to set, as it is the property that `move_and_slide` will use.

---

The code would be something like this (I'm making sure all the variable declarations are typed):

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed := 100

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        velocity.x = speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        velocity.x = -speed
    else:
        velocity.x = 0

    move_and_slide()
```

I can make that shorter and better (the following code supports analog input, you can configure dead zones in Input Map in Project Settings):

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed := 100

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    velocity.x = Input.get_axis("left", "right") * speed
    move_and_slide()
```

And here it is with the animated sprite and gravity (concerns clearly separated):

```
extends CharacterBody2D


@onready var animated_sprite := $AnimatedSprite


var speed := 100.0
var terminal_speed := 100.0
var gravity_acceleration := 300.0


func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    velocity.x = Input.get_axis("left", "right") * speed
    velocity.y = min(velocity.y + gravity_acceleration * delta, terminal_speed)

    move_and_slide()

    if is_zero_approx(velocity.x):
        animated_sprite.play("Idle")
    else:
        animated_sprite.play("Run")
        animated_sprite.flip_h = velocity.x > 0
```

This, of course, could be improved further.

Yet, again, I would like to encourage you to find an updated tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed a few things and now the code is working!                                                    But as you suggested, i will look for another Tutorial!                                                                                But atleast I understand what I did wrong!